# Can createElement method be applied on any node other than document?

Tags: javascript, html, createelement

```
 <html>
    <body>
        <style>
        .dot{
        width: 8px;
        height: 8px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        background-color: red;
        display: inline-block;
        }
        </style>

        <script>
        var dots = document.createElement("div");
        dots.className = "dots";
        document.body.appendChild(dots);

        var dot = document.body.createElement("div");
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

In the above segment,I tried creating a div node with variable name "dots" which was successful.But when I tried to create a div node with variable name "dot" using document.body.createElement,my attempt failed.Is it because that createElement method is supported only for document object and from there other nodes should be appended?

Comment: Yes, `createElement` is a method of `Document`. You create the element and then append it to whatever part of the DOM you want.

Comment: thanks.Can you suggest some material for exploring on javascript/DOM manipulation.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model

Comment: @GunacelanM It looks like you already understand it. `document.body.appendChild(dots)` is an example.

Comment: I want to add dot element as a child of dots elements for the above segment.Will the below part work?                                                          
       var dot = document.createElement("div");
            dot.className = "dot";
            document.body.dots.appendChild("dot");

Comment: Just use `dots.appendChild(dot)`

Answer (score 2):

As Barmer already commented, `createElement` only exists on *Document*: https://wiki.selfhtml.org/wiki/JavaScript/DOM/Document

To append it to the `body` tag of your DOM, you use `appendChild`of Node: https://wiki.selfhtml.org/wiki/JavaScript/DOM/Node/appendChild

So your own answer is correct